# Pulp Optimization with Pandas and NumPy (CLSP - Lot Sizing)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, linear-programming, pulp

For my master thesis I will be implementing a heuristic for the lot sizing problem (CLSP). As a start (and a benchmark for the heuristic) I wanted to implement the optimal solution for a small example, in order to get to know Python and its functionalities.

Doing so, I found several optimisation problems, but must of them were way more basic than the CLSP. I feel like I mostly struggle with the multiple indices of variables and the combination of Pandas and PuLP.

Btw.: Please don't mind the #german comments. They are just for my documentation.

This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pulp

# Liste für Perioden erstellen
PERIODS = list(range(1,7))

# Liste für Produkte erstellen
PRODUCTS = [1, 2]

# Liste für Ressourcen erstellen
RESSOURCES = [1]

# Minimierungsproblem definieren
clsp = pulp.LpProblem("Capacitated Lot-Sizing Problem", pulp.LpMinimize)

# Variablen deklarieren
# Nichtnegativitätsbedingungen werden durch LB=0 sichergestellt.
q       = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("Losgroesse fuer Produkt j in Periode t",
            ((k,t)  for k in PRODUCTS
                    for t in PERIODS),
                    0, None, 'Continuous')
y       = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("Lagerbestand für Produkt j am Ende der Periode t",
            ((k,t)  for k in PRODUCTS
                    for t in PERIODS),
                    0, None, 'Continuous')
gamma   = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("binaere Ruestvariable für Produkt j in Periode t",
            ((k,t)  for k in PRODUCTS
                    for t in PERIODS),
                    0, 1, 'Binary')

#Daten festlegen (Sollte in Zukunft in extra csv-Datei gespeichert werden)

#Rüstkostensatz pro Produkt
s = {1: 100,
     2: 50}

#Lagerhaltungskostensatz pro Produkt
h = {1: 4,
     2: 1}

#Produktionskosten pro Produkt & Periode
p = pd.DataFrame (np.array([(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)]), index=PRODUCTS ,columns=PERIODS)
'''1  2  3  4  5  6
1  2  2  2  2  2  2
2  3  3  3  3  3  3'''

#Bedarfsmengen pro Produkt & Periode
d = pd.DataFrame (np.array([(110, 49, 0, 82, 40, 65), (48, 75, 15, 10, 15, 70)]), index=PRODUCTS ,columns=PERIODS)
'''  1   2   3   4   5   6
1  110  49   0  82  40  65
2   48  75  15  10  15  70'''

#Big-M für binäre Rüstvariable
M = 1000

#Stückbearbeitungszeit für Produkt k an Ressource j
tb = pd.DataFrame (np.ones((1,2), dtype=np.int16), index=RESSOURCES ,columns=PRODUCTS)

#Rüstzeit für Produkt k auf Resource j
tr = pd.DataFrame (np.ones((1,2), dtype=np.int16), index=RESSOURCES ,columns=PRODUCTS)

#Kapazität der Ressource j in Periode t
b = pd.DataFrame (np.array([(160, 160, 160, 160, 120, 120)]), index=RESSOURCES ,columns=PERIODS)

# Zielfunktion aufstellen - Summe der Ruest-, Lager- & Produktionskosten:
clsp += pulp.lpSum([s[k]  * gamma[k][t] + h[k] * y[k][t] + p.loc[k][t] * q[k][t] for k in PRODUCTS for t in PERIODS]), "Total Costs"

# Restriktionen
for k in PRODUCTS:
    for t in PERIODS:
        clsp += y[k][t-1]  + q[k][t] - y[k][t]  == d.loc[k][t]  , "Lagerbilanzgleichung"
        clsp += q[k][t] - M * gamma[k][t] <= 0                  , "Big-M für Ruestvariable"
        clsp += pulp.lpSum([tb.loc[j][k] * q[k][t] + tr.loc[j][k] * gamma[k][t] <= b.loc[j][t], "Kapazitaetstrestriktion"] for j in RESSOURCES)

# Lineares Programm (LP) in Textdatei schreiben
clsp.writeLP("CLSP.lp")

# LP lösen
clsp.solve()

# Status der Loesung ausgeben: “Not Solved”, “Infeasible”, “Unbounded”, “Undefined” or “Optimal”
print("Status:", pulp.LpStatus[clsp.status])

# Ergebnisse für einzelne Variablen ausgeben
for v in clsp.variables():
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue, "%")

# Optimale Loesung der Zielfunktion ausgeben
print("Total Costs = ", value(clsp.objective))
```

I feel like this can't be too wrong.. Nevertheless, I am unsure about the following section. I am not sure, if I can put the indices (for k in PRODUCTS, etc.) before all of the constraints, if they have to be put behind each one respectively. At least this way I am not getting an error here...

```
for k in PRODUCTS:
    for t in PERIODS:
        clsp += y[k][t-1]  + q[k][t] - y[k][t]  == d.loc[k][t]  , "Lagerbilanzgleichung"
        clsp += q[k][t] - M * gamma[k][t] <= 0                  , "Big-M für Ruestvariable"
        clsp += pulp.lpSum([tb.loc[j][k] * q[k][t] + tr.loc[j][k] * gamma[k][t] <= b.loc[j][t], "Kapazitaetstrestriktion"] for j in RESSOURCES)
```

Further, when running that code, it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/frederic/Dropbox/2_Universita\u0308t Duisburg-Essen/0_Master Thesis/Implementierung/CLSP/clsp_v2.py", line 69, in <module>
    clsp += pulp.lpSum([s[k]  * gamma[k][t] + h[k] * y[k][t] + p.loc[k][t] * q[k][t] for k in PRODUCTS for t in PERIODS]), "Total Costs"
  File "/Users/frederic/Dropbox/2_Universita\u0308t Duisburg-Essen/0_Master Thesis/Implementierung/CLSP/clsp_v2.py", line 69, in <listcomp>
    clsp += pulp.lpSum([s[k]  * gamma[k][t] + h[k] * y[k][t] + p.loc[k][t] * q[k][t] for k in PRODUCTS for t in PERIODS]), "Total Costs"
KeyError: 1
```

With being line 69 my objective function:

```
clsp += pulp.lpSum([s[k]  * gamma[k][t] + h[k] * y[k][t] + p.loc[k][t] * q[k][t] for k in PRODUCTS for t in PERIODS]), "Total Costs"
```

I studied all online documentations and have been googling for hours, but yet, I haven't found a feasible solution, so any tips would be helpful!

I am fairly new to Python, so I appreciate you bearing with me here.

Cheers,
Frederic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for providing the code and good explanation. The issue is that the dictionaries `q`, `y`, and `gamma` that you are using to store your LpVariables are indexed on the `(k, t)` tuple, so you need to refer to them as `gamma[(k, t)]` instead of `gamma[k][t]`.

You'll have another issue when you get to this constraint

```
clsp += y[(k, t-1)]  + q[(k, t)] - y[(k, t)]  == d.loc[k][t]  , "Lagerbilanzgleichung"
```

because `t-1` won't be in `y` when `t` equals 1.

Comment: Thank @thomaskeefe! The objective function seems to work now. You are right with the other issue. I think I need to add a dummy period 0 then. Nevertheless all the constraints (basically all commands after the objective function) seem to result in various errors. For example, even when I put `y[(k,t)]` instead of `y[(k,t-1)]` it still returns an error.

Comment: You will also have another issue with your constraints: you are making your constraints in a for-loop, but each iteration of the for loop is trying to make a constraint with a duplicate name. PuLP does not allow that, so you will either have to not include constraint names, or make sure the constraint name is different for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: is there another way than the for-loop? I would then easily remove the constraint name. It's not that important. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: BTW. I added a variable `y[(1,0)]=0`so that the `t-1` case is covered. Nevertheless I am still getting an error here.. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/frederic/Dropbox/2_Universita\u0308t Duisburg-Essen/0_Master Thesis/Implementierung/CLSP/clsp_v2.py", line 76, in <module>
    clsp += y[(k,t-1)]  + q[k][t] - y[(k,t)] == d.loc[k][t]     , "Lagerbilanzgleichung"
KeyError: 1`

Comment: It's your `q` dictionary. To create unique constraint names in a for loop you can look into string formatting. It will look something like `"Lagerbilanzgleichung_{}_{}".format(k, t)`